# julia Plots equivalent with ggplot's fill

Tags: ggplot2, julia, bar-chart

Hello I am now interpreting R ggplot code into Julia using Plots.jl and StatPlots.

```
R"library(ggplot2)"
R"library(gcookbook)"
R"library(dplyr)"
R"upc <- uspopchange %>% arrange(desc(Change)) %>% slice(1:10)"    
R"ggplot(upc, aes(x = Abb, y = Change, fill = Region)) +
    geom_col()"
```

This is what I am trying to do.

I tried using groupedbar using StatsPlots

```
upc = rcopy(R"upc")
groupedbar(upc.Abb,upc.Change,   group =(upc.Region),
xlabel = "State", ylabel = "Change", bar_width = 0.5, 
size = (450,300))
```

But the results looks weird to me.

Can anyone help me?
Please let me know any reference. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package named [Gadfly](http://gadflyjl.org/stable/) that is based largely on Hadley Wickhams's ggplot2. And, it is written entirely in julia. You can try this code to plot something similar.

```
using Gadfly
upc = rcopy(R"upc")
sort!(upc,[:Abb]) #Sort it by Abb to show in plot

palette=["red","blue"] #Colors for bars
plot(upc, x = :Abb, y = :Change, color = :Region, Geom.bar, 
Theme(bar_spacing=1mm), Scale.color_discrete_manual(palette...))
```